# Getting puzzling performance with InputStream and Scanner

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, logging, inputstream

I seem to be running into an odd performance issue with InputStream and a scanner.

I'm using `tail -F` on a log file, essentially live streaming it to my code. When I do this I get approximately ~7,500,000 lines in 60 seconds(125,000 lines per sec). Fair enough.

Now since the log file is actually being written to faster than 125,000 lines/s I grep the log file to narrow down on my results.

When I run the updated `tail -F` commmand in my linux shell I get approximately 40,000 lines in 60 seconds (667 lines/s). Well beneath my 141,000 lines in 60 seconds when it was ungrepped.

However when I run the exact same command through my code, i get 16,000 lines in 60s (266 lines/s)! So somewhere i'm losing half of the lines and i'm scratching my head wondering why.

Code:

```
  public Boolean call() {
  //send command with no wait.
    final PrintStream out = new PrintStream(eCli.getOutputStream());

    //Notice the command terminator "\n" which is needed here for the command to be executed.
    out.print(tailCommandBuilder(logDir,fileName, filters));
    out.print((char)4);
    out.print('\n');
    final Scanner s = new Scanner(eCli.getInputStream());
    out.flush();
    //InputStream in =  new BufferedInputStream(eCli.getInputStream());
    StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
    sw.reset();
    sw.start();
    log.info("Stopwatch started.");
    double lineCounter = 0;
    //final BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    try {
        LOOP:
        while (keepRunning.get()) {

            if (s.hasNextLine()) {
                String st = s.nextLine();
                    lineCounter++;
            } else {
                keepRunning.getAndSet(false);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        log.error("Error in IORead: " + e.getMessage() + e.getStackTrace());

    } finally {
        sw.stop();
        log.info("Total Time: " + sw.getTime());
            s.close();
        log.warn("Total Lines Read: " + lineCounter);
        eCli.clearBuffer();
        eCli.disconnect();
    } 
    return true;
}
```

EDIT:

As asked before, eCli is an instance of an 'Extended Cli' class which implements a command line interface type instance. It uses InputStream/OutputStream to communicate.

I do not use --line-buffering with grep.

Comment: I presume the 'tail -f' output in both scenarios (`linux`/`java`) is identical? What is `eCli`?

Comment: Do you use --line-buffered flag with grep ?

Comment: I do not use --line-buffered. Ill investigate

eCli is a custom implementation of a CLI instance. Whats important is it uses an InputStream/OutputStream for communication

Comment: Could it be your `sleep(1)` being executed more often if the lines keep coming with 'bad' timing?

Comment: Actually Hanno, i've discovered that .hasNextLine() is blocking (if theres no input) anyways so that logic never gets hit. Just sloppy coding practices that I kept it there.

Answer (score 0):

I think i'm narrowing down on the answer here.

I've completely revamped the front-end code but really have only gone from 50% to 66% log capture percentage when grepped. The only difference is how quickly the new implementation pulls from InputStream.

The logs seem to 'burst' with their input. I'm thinking that somewhere there is a buffer that needs to be increased to handle this burst of info and allow the logs to average out.

Either the buffer needs to be increased in BufferedReader, InputStream or Shell.